# Reach page's ACF fields in wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this simple snippet in my header displaying the site's Main Menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'container'=> false ) ); 
?>
```

The menu displays the site's pages. Each page has a custom field added with Advanced Custom Fields called `text_color`. It's a color picker that let's me choose which color the menu item should have when hovering on it. I would like to have this field in the settings for the page itself, and not as a field added to the menu settings of Wordpress.

The hovering effect is created with a data attribute called `data-hover`. I then listen for `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events through JavaScript on each menu item, changing the text color of the menu item upon hovering, to the color code that's in the `data-hover`.

Since each menu item is connected to a page, I would like to be able to reach the page loop for each menu item, adding this `data-hover` to each anchor link in the menu item. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php in theme

```html
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_custom_data_atts_to_nav', 10, 4 );
function add_custom_data_atts_to_nav( $atts, $item, $args ) {

$atts['data-hover'] = $item->title;
return $atts;}
```

hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't this just add the title to the attribute? Is it possible to use custom fields (ACF fiels) with this method?

Comment: With great help from your answer, I figured out that instead of `$atts['data-hover'] = $item->title;` you should put 
   `$pageID = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
    $text_color = get_field('text_color', $pageID);
    $atts['data-hover'] = $text_color;` That gives me the result I wanted! :)

Comment: This idea helped me with implementing https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/ and adding extra css for menu item if checkbox is checked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work

But adding a class according to your ACF field could be possible if you get the items ID.

So something like this

```
function add_class_to_menu_item_by_acf($sorted_menu_objects, $args) {
    $theme_location = 'main-menu';  // Name, ID, or Slug of the target menu location



    if ($args->theme_location == $theme_location) {
        foreach ($sorted_menu_objects as $key => $menu_object) {
                //Get the menu objects post/page id - Check the object to see if this is the correct variable.
                $objectID = $menu_object->object_id;
                //Get the field
                $fieldColor = get_field('text_color', $objectID);
                if($fieldColor){
                    $menu_object->classes[] = "text_color_".$fieldColor;
                }

        }
    }

    return $sorted_menu_objects;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_class_to_menu_item_by_acf', 10, 2);
```

Again, I haven't tested this - but it might lead you on the right track?